# uncaught reference error: module is not defined

Tags: angular, node-modules

I'm fairly new to Angular and encountered this errormessage:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
>       at scripts.js:4

When I inspect scripts.js it references this line:

```
;module.exports = prop;
```

The file it belongs to is the index.js file of propper in node_modules

```
module.exports = prop;

function prop(obj, path, value) {
  if (!obj) return undefined;
  ....
}
```

Comment: could you provide some more code. prop ?

Comment: It's in the node_modules map, under propper. I didn't write it myself

Comment: try to delete node module folder and run npm install command once again. It may solve the problem

Comment: This error literally means `module` is not defined. Which raises the question of how are you importing this file into your project? Did you add this to a `<script>` tag in the Html?

Comment: @SivaRmK deleting node_modules and reinstalling them did not work

Comment: @Reactgular, I found a reference to the indexfile in my angular.json file under scripts[]. Deleting this line worked for me